# How to join two collection in mongo without lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collection, there name are **post** and **comment**.
The model structure is in the following.
I want to use aggregation query post and sort by comments like length sum, currently I can query a post comments like length sum in the following query statement.

My question is how can I query post and join comment collection in **Mongo version 2.6**. I know after Mongo 3.2 have a lookup function.

I want to query post collection and sort by foreign comments likes length. Is it have a best way to do this in mongo 2.6?

#### post

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a39e22c27308912334b4567"),
    "uid": "0",
    "content": "what is hello world mean?",
}
```

#### comment

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a595d8c2703892c3d8b4567"),
    "uid": "1",
    "post_id": "5a39e22c27308912334b4567",
    "comment": "hello world",
    "like": [
        "2"
    ]
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a595d8c2703892c3d8b4512"),
    "uid": "2",
    "post_id": "5a39e22c27308912334b4567",
    "comment": "hello stackoverflow",
    "like": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

#### Query a post comments like sum

```
db.getCollection('comment').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            post_id: "5a39e22c27308912334b4567"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "likeLength": {
                "$size": "$like"
            },
            "post_id": "$post_id"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: "$post_id",
            "likeLengthSum": {
                "$sum": "$likeLength"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best" way to query, as it'll really depend on your specific needs, but... you cannot perform a single query across multiple collections (aside from the `$lookup` aggregation pipeline function in later versions, as you already are aware).

You'll need to make multiple queries: one to your `post` collection, and one to your `comment` collection.

If you *must* perform a single query, then consider storing both types of documents in a single collection (with some identifier property to let you filter on either posts or comments, within your query).

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to join collections in the current MongoDB v6 without [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/),

I can predict two reasons that causing you the issues,

1. The `$lookup` is slow and expensive - **How to improve performance?**

   - [`$lookup` optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup-optimization):

     - Follow the guideline provided in the documentation
   - Use [indexs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/):

     - You can use the index on the reference collection's fields, as per your sample data you can create an index for `post_id` field, an index for `uid` field, or a compound index for both the fields on the basis of your use cases
     - You can read more about How to [Improve Performance with Indexes and Document Filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#improve-performance-with-indexes-and-document-filters)

       ```
       db.comment.createIndex({ "post_id": -1 });
       db.comment.createIndex({ "uid": -1 });
       // or
       db.comment.createIndex({ "post_id": -1, "uid": -1 });
       ```
   - [Document Filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#document-filters):

     - Use the `$match`, `$limit`, and `$skip` stages to restrict the documents that enter the pipeline
     - You can refer to the documentation for more detailed examples

       ```
       { $skip: 0 },
       { $limit: 10 } // as per your use case
       ```
   - Limit the `$lookup` result:

     - Try to limit the result of lookup by `$limit` stage,
     - Try to coordinate or balance with improved query and the UI/Use cases

2. You want to avoid `$lookup` - **How to improve the collection schema to avoid `$lookup`?**

   - Store the analytics/metrics:

     - If you are trying to get the total counts of the comments in a particular post then you must store the total count in the `post` collection whenever you get post get a new comment

       ```
       {
         "_id": ObjectId("5a39e22c27308912334b4567"),
         "uid": "0",
         "content": "what is hello world mean?",
         // new fields
         "total_comments": 10
       }
       ```
   - Store minimum reference data:

     - If you want to show the comments of a particular post, you can limit the result for ex: show 5 comments per post
     - You can also store a max of 5 latest comments in the `post` collection to avoid the `$lookup`, whenever you get the latest comment then add it and just remove the oldest comment from 5 comments

       ```
       {
         "_id": ObjectId("5a39e22c27308912334b4567"),
         "uid": "0",
         "content": "what is hello world mean?",
         // new fields
         "total_comments": 10,
         "comments": [
           {
             "_id": ObjectId("5a595d8c2703892c3d8b4567"),
             "uid": "1",
             "comment": "hello world"
           },
           {
             "_id": ObjectId("5a595d8c2703892c3d8b4512"),
             "uid": "2",
             "comment": "hello stackoverflow"
           }
         ]
       }
       ```
   - Must read about [Reduce `$lookup` Operations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/schema-suggestions/reduce-lookup-operations/)
   - Must read about [Improve Your Schema](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/performance-advisor/schema-suggestions/)