# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, robo3t

I'm trying to run a script in `Robo 3T 1.2.1` which used to work long time ago:

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $lookup: { from:"users", localField:"_id", foreignField:"_id", as:"user" } }, 
    { $sort: { count: -1 } }
]);
 
for (var i = 1; i <= 250; i++) {
    current = cursor.next()
    print(current["_id"].toString())
    print(current["user"][0]["currentName"])
    print(current["count"])
}
```

But it returned an error:

```
Error:
Assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
    "code" : 16436,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:14
```

[image]

`$ mongo --version` returned `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12` on the server. Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Edit 1:** This script used to return the users who have lots of logs, does anyone know if there is an easy way to rewrite it without `$lookup`?

Comment: what `db.version()' shows?

Comment: `db.version()` shows `2.6.12`

Comment: Why do you use a 10(!) years old version of MongoDB? I am surprised that you even find a tool which is still able to connect to such ancient database.

Answer (score 0):

This is too ancient database. It looks like `$lookup` was introduced in 3.2 server. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/thoughts-on-new-feature-lookup)

Comment: But why I remember that this script worked before on the database?

Comment: idk :) maybe it was diff version?

Comment: I did not change database; i did not change robo 3T either.

Comment: see release notes here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.6/release-notes/3.2/#new-aggregation-stages, so no way to use $lookup with 2.6 server

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite this query?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965627/how-to-join-two-collection-in-mongo-without-lookup

Comment: This is really odd, I have written down several scripts with `$lookup` which I believe worked one year ago.

Comment: :man-shrugging: